# nuxt3 using response from graphql, Cannot read properties of null (reading 'class')

Tags: javascript, vuejs3, nuxtjs3

My nuxt query is returning a block of JSON like this,

```
{
    "typeHandle": "builderAccordionBlock",
    "data": [
      {
        "title": "Frequently Asked Questions",
        "numberedAccordion": "Grid",
        "accordionBlockBackgroundColour": {
          "class": "block--bg-charcoal",
          "color": [
            "#363636"
          ],
          "label": "Dark Grey",
          "__typename": "accordionBlockBackgroundColour"
        },
        "accordionBlockFullWidth": true,
        "accordionBlockSection": [
          {
            "accordionRowHeader": "Do you offer quotes over the phone?",
            "accordionRowBody": "<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Morbi ullamcorper tortor sapien, id convallis orci auctor eu. Etiam at risus eu ligula facilisis pellentesque. Aliquam lacinia erat eu sollicitudin aliquam. Donec in convallis ante. Nunc ut vehicula nulla. Nunc vehicula aliquam est ac consectetur. Mauris consectetur lorem eget pulvinar ultrices.</p>",
            "__typename": "accordionBlockSection_accordionRow_BlockType"
          }
         ]
      }
    ]
  }
```

I do the following in component,

```
 <div class="accordion__block px-5" :class="accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class">
```

But get the error,

> Cannot read properties of null (reading 'class')

I also get the error trying,

```
<div class="accordion__block px-5" :class="[accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class]">
```

I have tried computing it,

```
const backgroundColour = computed(() => { return accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class }
```

I can see the object is going into the component as a prop I am utterly at a loss why I cannot access it.

If I do,

```
<div class="accordion__block px-5" :class="[accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class]">
```

I get

```
<div class="accordion__block px-5 color label class ___typename">
```

rendered, something wierd is happening, or I am being totally thick?

Answer (score 0):

In the JSON, `data` is an array, without seeing your code to determine if you are accessing the class attribute in a for loop or how you have even parsed the JSON in the first place... I have to make the assumption you are not intentionally iterating the array and always expect the array size to be 1?

So, without the use of a for loop, you would need to access index of the array at position 0 (zero)?

```
data[0].accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class
```

Answer (score 0):

Depending on your code (which we do not have here) the data from request can be available only after the page is rendered. In this case the data is null and to prevent this error you have to add something like this to your element

`<div v-if="data" class="accordion__block px-5" :class="data[0].accordionBlockBackgroundColour.class">`

here you render element only if the data from request is available. Also i presume that the "data" is the part of your response object and you properly extract it before passing to the component. The good habit when getting errors like this is to console.log the object you are passing to the component